# Accessing non-public members

Tags: php, getter-setter

I am creating domain objects. I want these objects to have setters that will check the validity of the value to be assign to each property, but I also want to be able to set this property without performing the check if the data is assumed correct.

I could do the following :

```
class DO_Group
{
    protected $_name = null;

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->_name;
    }

    public function setName( $name )
    {
        $length = strlen( $name );

        if( 4 <= $length && $length <= 16 && preg_match( '^[A-Z]*(_[A-Z]*)*$', $name ) == 1 )
            $this->_name = $name;
        else
            throw new Exception( '::DO_Group::setName() - Invalid name.' );
    }
}
```

But in a case where the $name passed to setName() is known to be valid, I would have to call setName, and thus perform an unneeded check, to set that property.

I could use the reflection API or the debug trace hack, but I want to use none of these two ways because they are bad performance wise when used many times (and are dirty, IMO).

I thought about adding a method that doesn't check the value :

```
public function setNameNoCheck( $name )
{
    $this->_name = $name;
}
```

But in this case, making the property non-public doesn't make sense. And if I chose to make it public, a code user might forget to check it when needed.

Could I do :

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    public function setProperty( $name, $value )
    {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
}
```

And make my domain objects extends this class ? It is correct PHP to refer undeclared properties ? (since they doesn't exist in the base class)

Comment: I'm fairly sure your base class idea would work, but you might want to give the method a name that indicates that its purpose is to bypass setter checks. Depending on the use case, you could also do a version that accepts an associative array and sets all of the indicated properties at once.

Answer (score 1):

I guess my suggestion would be to just use the method you have now for both instances:

```
public function setName( $name )
{
        $length = strlen( $name );

        if( 4 <= $length && $length <= 16 && preg_match( '^[A-Z]*(_[A-Z]*)*$', $name ) == 1 )
            $this->_name = $name;
        else
            throw new Exception( '::DO_Group::setName() - Invalid name.' );
}
```

In this case, you can be certain your database will always retain its integrity.  And even there are a few instances where you are POSITIVE the value is valid, the overhead would be minimal.  It just seems to be a clean solution that is guaranteed to work.

#### EDIT :

If the object already exists in the database, why not just create a class method to handle that?  Then call it when you are pulling values directly out of the database..

```
public function populateFields( $row )
{
    $this->_name = $row['name'];
    // ... populate other fields here
}
```

This would populate all of the fields at once instead of having to write and call individual functions for each property.

Comment: Yeah but if my database is guaranteed to be valid, there's no point checking right ? If it was only a matter of few tests, that would be ok, but if i have to load say a hundred or rows from a table, each containing several properties involving the use of a regexp, that's not negligible.

Comment: @Virus721 I guess I was thinking more along the lines of insertions and updates to a database.  If you are populating these fields I would recommend a different approach... See edit in a second

Comment: @Joel: Pardon my "Unix Way" question here, but I am curious. Have you experienced speed issues with this piece of code already? If not, are you not technically "prematurely optimizing" code that m ay end up not needing any optimization at all? Again, I'm an old man and have been writing software for years, but it seems that it would be best to make things work right, THEN make them work faster. It may be that you don't need this optimization at all. YMMV.

Comment: @mrunion I do not think I did any premature optimization... I was arguing that **the overhead might not be an issue**. Did you perhaps mean to address that comment to Virus721?

Comment: @Joel: Yes. Wrong copied/pasted name. Please accept my apologies. (See, told you I was old! I get confused!)

Comment: @mrunion It might seem like a premature optimisation, but if i know in advance that i'm going to do something a large amount of times, i should not ignore possible optimisations. It's not like i had replaced `<= 4` by `< 5`.

Comment: @Joël I thought about something similar to that to get an array of property_name => value to know which columns should be included in the query `(function toMap() { return array( 'name' => $this->_name ); }`) and the reverse way with a populateFields method as you suggest. but if i do that i might as well just use regular arrays.

Comment: @Virus721 Using regular arrays would work fine.  I just think it is an effective solution which is not incredibly complex.

Comment: Well i've been using arrays until now but i wanted to add some OOP-style into my code to make it easier to read. I think that i will simply make my properties public and let the user know, using the documentation, that checking the value requires to call the setter.

Comment: @Virus721 Probably not a bad idea.  The individual set functions should be used when not reading directly from the database.  Make sure that is clear.  If they don't follow the documentation, then their code will break... which is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

If you use PHP 5.4+ then here is a good pice of code for you. I came up with this a couple of months back. If you're on PHP 5.3 or less, you can still make it work using `call_user_func`. However with the help of anonymous functions it is much more clean, and verbose.

The idea is to make a kind of a `friend` object. Similar to `friend` classes in C++, but operating on specific objects instead of classes.

So let's get started. First we need to prepare your class a bit:

```
class DoGroup
{
    protected $_name = null;

    public function makeFriend(IDoGroupFriend $newFriend)
    {
        $newFriend->plugNameSetter(function($name){
            $this->_doSetName($name);
        });
    }

    public function setName( $name )
    {
        // do the costly checking here...
        /// and set the variable:
        $this->_doSetName($name);
    }

    protected function _doSetName($name)
    {
        $this->_name = $name;
    }
}
```

Next, we would define that friend interface:

```
interface IDoGroupFriend
{
    public function plugNameSetter(callable $nameSetterFn);
}
```

And now we can create friends:

```
class ExampleFriend implements IDoGroupFriend
{
    private $_nameSetterFn = null;

    public function plugNameSetter(callable $nameSetterFn)
    {
        $this->_nameSetterFn = $nameSetterFn;
    }

    public function setTheNameFromFriend($name)
    {
        $nameSetterFn = $this->_nameSetterFn;
        $nameSetterFn($name);
    }
}
```

Finally, we can use the friends as follows:

```
$Main = new DoGroup();
$Friend = new ExampleFriend();

$Main->makeFriend($Friend);

// tadam!
$Friend->setTheNameViaFriend('name via friend');
```

Ofcourse your real implementation could be much more sophisticated then just blindly passing the name. If the source of the `$name` (the `ExampleFriend` object in this case) is trusted then I'm assuming it comes from a different trusted source. In such case you would implement the `setTheNameFromFriend` differently - for example as an databese fetch method.

Also you'd probably don't want to have the `DoGroup::makeFriend()` method public. I usually invoke this method only from constructor of the `DoGroup` class, so I like to meke it private.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention that i'm limited to PHP 5.2, sorry. Your solution looks interesting but seems a bit complicated to understand, especially for a user who hasn't asked himself the questions i'm currently asking myself. I would like to keep things intuitive.

Comment: It is a matter of perspective whether it is complicated. Once you implement this you are not exposing it to other users. They will see only your public API, and wouldn't care about internals.

Comment: True true, but i can't use closures anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Create safe mode ($this->safeMode = false) and

```
       public function setName( $name )
    {
if ($this->safeMode===true){ $this->_name = $name; return;}

            $length = strlen( $name );

            if( 4 <= $length && $length <= 16 && preg_match( '^[A-Z]*(_[A-Z]*)*$', $name ) == 1 )
                $this->_name = $name;
            else
                throw new Exception( '::DO_Group::setName() - Invalid name.' );
    }
```

set safeMode to true if data is from database or other "safe" source (or class extends database class)

Comment: Thanks that's a good idea, but i would like users to have a minimum amount of code to write and things to think about. This solution would require them to take into account the value of safeMode, which i'd like to avoid.

Comment: so use extends. In parent class set protected $safeMode=false. In child class (this one for users) set protected $safeMode=false on the other hand in child class (this safe one) protected $safeMode=true. I that case users don't have to set anything. Of course I mean to set this in class properties not by $this->setSafeMode(true);